# Test a function that takes 3 integers for all possible cases

Tags: javascript, testing, integer

I have a function that takes in 3 integer numbers which can be anything.

The function performs some complex comparisons on the numbers and calls/returns accordingly.

```
var A = 1; could be anything between +/- Number.MAX_VALUE
var B = 2; 
var C = 3;

result = TheFunction(A,B,C);
```

I need to test how well the logic in my `TheFunction` holds for all possible values.

How do I test this function for all possible values?

Obviously I can't plug in all numbers and all combinations of all numbers!

What would be the best amount of values (and what would they be) that I can plug in and be sure that my function will work for all possible values??

Comment: what do the `TheFunction` do?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about the function, one can only speak in generalities. The most common trouble cases are at and near boundaries of ranges. These would include:

- maximum value
- minimum value
- maximum value - 1
- minimum value + 1
- -1, 0, and 1

Add to those a couple of positive and negative mid-range values, and you have 9 or 10 numbers to test for each argument. With three arguments, that is about 1000 cases.

Knowing something about the internals of the function may allow you to reduce the cases or may suggest additional values or value combinations that might be sources of trouble.

P.S. Due to roundoff, `Number.MAX_VALUE - 1` probably just evaluates to `Number.MAX_VALUE`. You should be aiming for the largest *representable* number less than `Number.MAX_VALUE`. This also suggests a couple of additional possible trouble spots: the largest and smallest integers, which according to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) are:

```
var biggestInt = 9007199254740992;
var smallestInt = -9007199254740992;
```